# How to move my data to end of partition?

Tags: security, dd

To avoid `dd` alike destroy my personal files, it'd be better to move them to the higher number of sectors that near the rear of partition, and as I don't have separated /home, I also need to move the system files to front. Without overwriting any data can be seen by file explorer, how can I make the move (maybe it looks like resize in gparted)

Answer (score 1):

Native Linux filesystems which sport defragmentation (ext4/xfs) don't offer the luxury of choosing where your files end up being, so your only option seems to be backing up your data, repartitioning and restoring.

Backing up data is crucial anyways. Just moving your user data somewhere will not save you from from mechanical/electrical failures of your disk storage and other commands which could kill your data, e.g. `rm -rf`.

Comment: `dd` is able to write/read data to/from a specific sector, and I have to check this sector is free, its not an easy job when I have to move thousands of files.

Comment: It's a mammoth task - good luck with that - just don't destroy your FS in the process.

Comment: I just know this basic solution but impossible, so I'm here ask a quicker one.